# How does lazy loading in Ionic affect the produced mobile app?

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I am using Ionic3 + Angular5 for a mobile app development. I am new to Ionic3.

I know lazy loading for a webapp can increase performance since it only loads the component it is needing. But for an mobile app, when the entire app has been downloaded to the phone, does lazy loading still apply here? And is there any side affect for the mobile app when I use lazy loading?

Answer (score 2):

*does lazy loading still apply here?*

> Yes, since the app treats the page as one webview.

*And is there any side affect for the mobile app when I use lazy loading?*

> the only side effect is that you have some lagging. you can resolve this by preloading some pages based on priority.

Refer to this [article](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/), and part [2](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/)

Answer (score 2):

> But for an mobile app, when the entire app has been downloaded to the phone, does lazy loading still apply here

Yes, lazy loading still applies because lazy loading is not only about getting the components which are needed, This also means that, **the boot time of the app will be faster because only a chunk of your overall javascript code needs to be parsed**.

If you have a complex app with too many pages, then using lazy loading will significantly improve your bootup time and performance.